# Starteck KVM to USB crashcart install on Ubuntu 18.04 python issue

Tags: python-2.7

After installing the Startech USB Crash Cart Adapter I try to run the adapter by double clicking on the icon, and it never loads. I tried rebooting and the issue persists. When I run the adapter from the Terminal using `usb-crash-cart-adapter` I get the following Error:

[image]

I downloaded the Linux package from https://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/Portable-USB-PS-2-KVM-Console-Adapter-for-Notebook-PCs~NOTECONS01. And I installed it using gdebi.

It appears to be a python dependency issue, but I am not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, which resulted in a phone call to startech and them publishing an updated driver, but that still didn't resolve the issue.

To fix it do the following steps.

1. CD to your directory where the file is located. Run `cd /opt/usb-crash-cart-adapter/20180327/guts`
2. In here you will see the libz.so.1 file. It is always good to make a copy of the original file just in case, so run `cp libz.so.1 libz.so.1.old`
3. Create a link to the existing libz.so.1 file on your system. Run, `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1`
4. Reboot the machine.

After that your crash cart adapter should be good to go. In my case the icons where also not showing before, but were resolved with this fix.